# Как залить war на tomcat сервер?

Tags: java, tomcat, war

Мне нужно в java-коде найти war-файл и залить его на tomcat8. 
Не пойму как это делается. На официальном сайте посмотрел, либо ничего не понял, либо нет ничего.
То есть где-то на диске лежит файл C:\test\test.war
я в другом приложении нахожу его и хочу залить на сервер. руками не хочу это делать, так как автоматизирую процесс.  rest api не смог так

Кто может подсказать или дать пример как в java залить определенный файл на сервер?

Comment: Вы можете положить файл на удаленный сервер через FTP или SFTP, в папку `webapps/`, как обычный файл. Либо [по HTTP через интерфейс менеджера Tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19954351/5694145). Но самый простой вариант без java кода - curl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apache-tomcat-8.0.26\conf\tomcat-users.xml добавить пользователя, у которого будут права на деплой

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="admin" roles="manager-script"/>
```

manager-gui - для доступа к админке
manager-script для деплоя.

далее 
    http://localhost:8080/manager/text/deploy?path=/foo&war=file:C:\workflow\calendar-1.1.war

лог:
    OK - Deployed application at context path /foo

вот [ссылка](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_A_New_Application_from_a_Local_Path)

Answer (score 2):

В java-коде нет war-файла. Вы компилируете свой java-код, добавляете папку WEB-INF с web.xml и пакуете в war вместо jar.

Это можно сделать или в IDE, или различными сборщиками (Maven, Gradle, Ant и т.д.)
Подробнее можно посмотреть тут:
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0)

или загуглить по "war file structure java"

Когда вы получили war файл (например myapp.war), его нужно задеплоить. Это можно сделать кинув его в папку webapps

Comment: @Rsstam я подкорректировал вопрос. это не то, что я хотел

Comment: @SeniorAutomator не знаю как в томкате, в JBoss/WildFly можно в том числе задеплоить через админскую консоль (веб), но это еще сложнее автоматизировать, нежели кинуть файл в папку по SSH